# Does yesod-bin compile under GHC 9.2.4?

Tags: ghc, yesod

i have a small yesod website that compiled under ghc 8.?

I'm trying to work with ghc 9.2.4.  Depending on what I try, i either die from conflicting versions when I try to build

stack build yesod-bin

If I get yesod-bin to build using a mess of specific paths in stack.yaml, I get an error when I execute

stack exec -- yesod devel

The short version of my question:  has someone successfully built yesod-bin under ghc 9.2.4?